# "Обошли неспешной прогулкой" — это правильно?

Tags: стилистика, лексическая-сочетаемость

*И тогда мы еще раз **неспешной прогулкой** обошли монастырь...*

Это авторский вариант или нет, можно не выделять курсивом?

Поменять на *обошли неспешно*? Но так смысл частично меняется.

Answer (score 2):

Слово "прогулкой" в роли обстоятельства образа действия встречается, хотя и нечасто, в литературе 19-начала 20 веков.

> тихой прогулкой возвратились домой... (А. П. Беляев, "Из воспоминаний", 1880)
>
> Мы иногда ездили туда прогулкой. (А. А. Татищев, "Земля и люди", 1928)

Comment: Большое спасибо, это интересно. То, что когда-то существовало в речи, иногда возвращается.

Answer (score 1):

Красиво звучит. Как-то художественно. Но это однозначно нестандартно. Оборот отвечает на вопрос *как?* Какое-то наречие получается.
Стандартный вариант — *неспешно прогуливаясь*.

Для увеличения уровня художественности (можно сказать, своебразности) довольно часто используют нестандартные речевые обороты, но звучащие. Особенно в стихах.

Comment: Спасибо за ваше мнение.